# Queries in two tables without "inner join"

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I wonder what is the difference of these two queries and which one hás the best performance?

```
SELECT employee.*, company.name  FROM 
company,
employee
WHERE
employee.company_id = company.id AND
company.id = '365'
```

or

```
SELECT employee.*, company.name  FROM 
company 
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.company_id  = company.id
WHERE
company.id = '365'
```

Comment: The performance is the same.  The second is much, much, much, much preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a different notation. No other difference.